# Maximo Anywhere Multi Language

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

We are going to install French language pack for Maximo 7.6.0.5 and we also want to reflect the french language in Maximo Anywhere. Will I get french language pack automatically in maximo Anywhere if I install french language pack in Maximo core? If not, please let help me what are the files i need to change to get french translations in Maximo Anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Maximo Anywhere GUI is based on the device's language. All supported languages are available in the apk/ipa you will be using. As long as your device is set to the French locale you should see the application in French.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some custom labels in Anywhere you will need to see this instruction here:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSPJLC_7.6.2/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/pdf_si_mpl_customize.pdf

There is one part that describes that situation:

> Changing field labels The labels for fields in the mobile apps are
> defined in the app.xml file. You can change any of the labels to match
> your implementation of Maximo Anywhere. Procedure
>
> 1. In MobileFirst Studio, go to the Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere\apps\app_name\ artifact directory and open the
>    app.xml file with the XML editor.
> 2. On the Design tab, expand the view that contains the label attribute you want to change and enter the new name.
> 3. If you translate the mobile app, change the name of the label in the artifact.js file for each supported language. For example, if the
>    base language of the mobile app is English and you translate the app
>    to French, change the label name in the artifact.js file in the
>    Anywhere\MaximoAnywhere
>    apps\WorkExecution\common\js\application\translation\nls\fr directory.
> 4. Save your changes. The application is built automatically.
> 5. Optional: To preview your changes in the mobile browser simulator, right-click on the application folder and select Run As > Preview

I will add also some useful links here that are describing how Maximo works with multiple languages.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/enabling-multi-language-support-simplified-set-instructions

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/general-multi-language-questions-maximo

https://bportaluri.com/2013/05/add-language-pack-to-maximo.html

https://maximosecrets.com/2019/06/06/maximo-languages-and-language-tables/